# Error in calculation of hitting time of -1 in a biased random walk on the integers

Tags: probability, random-walk

We have a random walk on the integers ${...,-1,0,...}$ which starts at $0$. It moves left with probability $p$ and right with probability $1-p$. I wanted to calculate the expected amount of time it would take this walk to reach $-1$ for the first time. The formula I arrived at is:

$\mathbb{E}{[T]} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}(2n+1)p^{n+1}(1-p)^{n}C_n$, where $C_n$ is an $n^{th}$ Catalan number. This is because:

1. You cannot reach $-1$ in an even number of steps.
2. It takes $n+1$ left steps and $n$ right steps to reach $-1$ in $2n+1$ steps.
3. The number of ways to order these steps is equal to the number of ways you can organize parentheses $(( () ))$ in a legal way = the $n^{th}$ Catalan number.

What I noticed (using the estimation $C_n \sim 4^n / (n^{3/2} \sqrt{\pi})$ is that this formula actually *converges* for any $p$ other than $p = 1/2$, including $p > 1/2$. However this does not make sense; seemingly it should converge for only values of $p$ smaller than $1/2$.

Where is my error? My thinking is that maybe the correct calculation should include also the probability that $T = \infty$, i.e. $P(T = \infty) \cdot \infty$ should be formally taken into account in the summation. But I do not know if this is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $H$ is the event that $-1$ is ever hit then $\mathbb P(H)=\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}p^{n+1}(1-p)^{n}C_n$

This will be $1$ when $\frac12 \lt p \lt 1$  but less than $1$ when $0 \lt p \lt \frac12$

Your expression actually calculates
$$\mathbb E[T\mid H] \,\mathbb P(H) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}(2n+1)p^{n+1}(1-p)^{n}C_n$$ and it is quite reasonable that this converges when $p \not = \frac12$

You can turn this into the conditional expectation
$$\mathbb E[T\mid H] = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}(2n+1)p^{n+1}(1-p)^{n}C_n}{\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}p^{n+1}(1-p)^{n}C_n}$$ which is $\frac{1}{2p-1}$ for $\frac12 \lt p \lt 1$, but is $\frac{1}{1-2p}$ for $0 \lt p \lt \frac12$. You could say  $$\mathbb E[T\mid H]=\left|\dfrac{1}{2p-1}\right|$$

So for example with $p=0.9$ or $p=0.1$ you get $\mathbb E[T\mid H] =1.25$, while with $p=0.6$ or $p=0.4$ you get $\mathbb E[T\mid H] =5$.  This makes sense intuitively since with $p$ close to $1$ you are likely to hit $-1$ early, while with $p$ close to $0$ you are unlikely to ever hit $-1$ unless you hit it in the first attempt

Comment: I still has a doubt, look at $\mathbb{P}(H)$ you've wrote. By rewritting it we get $\mathbb{P}(H) = p\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}p^n(1-p)^nC_n$, which gives, in my opinion, a pretty deep insight on the series and the values it converges to. From here it is not obvious in any way what is the value of the $\mathbb{P}(H)$. Only the convergence for any $p \neq \frac{1}{2}$. Also, I do not understand why my expression is not an $\mathbb{E}(T | H)$ (eye openning here), why do you claim it is multiplied by $\mathbb{P}(H)$?

Comment: Your original expression adds up the $2n+1$ number of steps to first hit $-1$ multiplied the probability of first hitting $-1$ with $2n+1$ steps.  So the sum only counts cases where $-1$ is in fact hit, and that has a probability $\mathbb P(H)$ which is $1$ for $\frac12 \lt p \lt 1$ while for $0 \lt p \lt \frac12$ it is $\frac{p}{1-p}$.  More generally you would have  $\mathbb E[T] =\mathbb E[T\mid H] \,\mathbb P(H)+ \mathbb E[T\mid H^c] \,\mathbb P(H^c)$ but you have dropped the second part, which is zero for $\frac12 \lt p \lt 1$ while for $0 \lt p \lt \frac12$ it is infinite.